# how to design the table convenient insert and select,and good design

Tags: database-design, polymorphic-associations

i want statistics visit information data,the information have two different table,
i design table use type tell the different table,
such as

```
CREATE TABLE visitor(
visitorId BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
informationId BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
visitCount BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
type -- "news" or "tech"
PRIMARY KEY (visitorId , informationId ),
);
```

i know it is polymorphic-associations,and the table is not follow 3NF,
A transitive dependency is when one non-key field's value depends on another
non-key field's value.
type column depends on visitedInformation,
i try to split table,

```
CREATE TABLE newVisit (
informationId BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
visitorId BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (issue_id, comment_id),
FOREIGN KEY (informationId) REFERENCES news(id),
FOREIGN KEY (visitorId) REFERENCES Visitor(id)
);

CREATE TABLE newVisit (
informationId BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
visitorId BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (issue_id, comment_id),
FOREIGN KEY (informationId) REFERENCES news(id),
FOREIGN KEY (visitorId) REFERENCES Visitor(id)
);

CREATE TABLE visitor(
visitorId BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
informationId BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
visitCount BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (visitorId , informationId ),
);
```

but the foreign key visitorId,cannot identify the row of visitor,
should i use the table design?

```
CREATE TABLE newVisit (
informationId BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
visitorId BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (issue_id, comment_id),
foreign key (informationId , visitorId ) 
    references visitor(informationId , visitorId ),
);
```

i don't think the table is convenient to insert data,i have to join newVisit and visitor to insert,but if i use the first design,i just join one table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As best as I can make out, you have two entity tables, Visitors and News. Now you want to track...what exactly? Which news... items?... each visitor accesses? Sounds ominous.

If this is correct, then you want to associate many visitors to many news thingies. This is a simple intersection table:

```
create table NewsVisits(
    VisitorID  int  not null,
    InfoID     int  not null,
    VisitCount int  not null default 1, -- to allow same visitor to access same info many times???
    constraint  PK_NewsVisits primary key( VisitorID, InfoID ),
    constraint  FK_NewsVisits_Visitor foreign key( VisitorID )
        references Visitors( ID ),
    constraint  FK_NewsVisits_Info foreign key( InfoID )
        references News( ID )
);
```

So when a visitor accesses a news item, insert that information -- unless that visitor has already accessed that news item already in which case you increment the visit count.